# Wave Analytics - JSON Metadata Tag error

Tags: analytics, einstein-analytics

Trying to do some Wave magic, and looking to get in a connector setup... running into a road block though.

The csv works fine through manual upload same with JSON.  But if not doing it manual through the UI I get an error...

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000233074&language=en_US

"*Error executing node digest: failed converting CSV data to 'bin' format: empty edgemart - nothing loaded from CSV file, load.* This indicates that the source data has no good rows and could not be processed. No error log will result as the file completely failed."

Anyone have any insights/ideas on this issue and why that would happen?  Not really sure how else to troubleshoot, following the documentation isn't helping.

---

Updated error message: Internal error: Input length = 1. Please contact Salesforce Customer Support.: Metadata JSON

Comment: I would recommend you to double check the CSV format of the file .This definitely has to do with file format

Comment: I will go double-check that now.

Comment: Updated with new error message: Internal error: Input length = 1. Please contact Salesforce Customer Support.: Metadata JSON --- I am opening a ticket as well, not sure if I'll get much help from SF on it though.

Comment: Hi All, Anyway you can share the CSV ? I can check it out...

Comment: Andrew, we were able to get it sorted out, thanks for the willingness to help!

Comment: Hey, for posterity's sake, you could post a quick summary of what you did - it could help the next person and you might get some rep :)